# how to write third party media sink(muxer) in media foundation

Tags: render, mediarecorder, ms-media-foundation

Media Sink components fall into two general categories,renderer and archive sink. for playback, I can use windows default renderer. but now I want to encode some file, and write out to a file. does windows media foundation have some sample code about how to develop media sink(muxer). just like MPEG1SOURCE samplecode and decoder samplecode in the sdk.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In SDK, there is a sample WAVSINK